# Finding saved data from mongo shell (no output)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here is the code for initialization

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/gpsdb');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('open', function () {
  // now we can start talking
});
```

After successful opening, I am saving data like this, it's giving me no errors.

```
function saveGPSData(data){
  var newData = new GPSData(data);
  newData.save(function(err){
    if(err)
        return console.error(err);

  });
}
```

Now in mongo shell, I am trying to retrieve that data but it's giving me empty output.

```
> use gpsdb
> db.GPSData.find();
>
```

It's giving me no output. Also can I found what models are there in gpsdb?

Here is the full source code http://pastebin.com/K7QPYAx8

JUST FOUND THAT in db folder there these files for my db created by mongodb

```
/data/db/gpsdb.0
/data/db/gpsdb.1
/data/db/gpsdb.n
```

Comment: Are you using safe writes?  By default Mongodb uses fire-and-forget writes which won't report errors.  If you're not using safe writes, then its possible that the write is failing silently without reporting an error.  Check out http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shell I did the following

```
>use gpsdb
switched to gpsdb
>db show collections
gpsdatas
```

From here I found that collection name is gpsdatas...... Not sure why its adding extra (s) to my modal, although you can see from the code that I am setting Modal to

```
var GPSData = mongoose.model('GPSData', GPSDataSchema);
```

Now using the shell its working like this

```
>db.gpsdatas.find()
```

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start to get a quick answer is

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongoose-orm

the community is very responsive :)